# Get index of selected choice in ui-select - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I use `angularjs` with `ui-select` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/)

I have this code:

```
<ui-select tagging="addTagging" tagging-tokens="ENTER" ng-change="sourceChanged()" ng-model="sender" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" ng-disabled="disabled">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices data-id="$index" repeat="item.name as item in places | filter:$select.search">
        {{item.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Inside the `sourceChanged` function I want to know the index of the selected item.. Now i just have the value (`scope.sender`)..
I can search for the value in `places` array but it's not good enough for me because there is a chance that there will be several items with the same value...

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong repeat expr.

```
<ui-select-choices data-id="$index" repeat="item.name as item in places | filter:$select.search">
        {{item.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
```

You are telling ui-select, iterate trought places and bind item.name inside model, change it to

```
<ui-select-choices data-id="$index" repeat="item in places | filter:$select.search">
        {{item.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
```

It will bind complete item object to ngModel , so you have original item from array of places.

Comment: if you want index you jast have to call  `$scope.places.indexOf($scope.sender)` , it will return index inside original array